# Why, when using ViewPager2, the software keyboard hides the edittext and raises the floating button?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-viewpager2

Why, when using ViewPager2, the software keyboard hides the EditText and raises the floating button? When using ViewPager, everything is done the other way around. Hides the floating button and leaves the EditText visible.

This is ViewPager. All is right. Floating Button is hidden. EditText is visible.

[image: ViewPager]

And this is ViewPager2. I've only replaced ViewPager with ViewPager2. And FragmentPagerAdapter with FragmentStateAdapter.
I'm sure it shouldn't be like that.

[image: ViewPager2]

I also replaced `tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)`
with this one:

```
TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabs, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
}.attach()
```

How to make it so that when using ViewPager2, the software keyboard behaves the same way as when using ViewPager?

Comment: Isn't `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` working?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. By the way, why doesn't the ViewPager need `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`?

Comment: Not sure if that related to `ViewPager`; but I think the default behavior of showing the keyboard is to try not to shrink the layout i.e. try to resize it so that it's totally appeared but `adjustPan` will cut the top part of the layout so that the `EditText` or the widget that you type in appears